# Clojure Transients Example - No significant speedup

Tags: clojure

I copied the code from:

http://clojure.org/transients

but my results differ signifiantly from what was posted.

```
(defn vrange [n]
  (loop [i 0 v []]
    (if (< i n)
      (recur (inc i) (conj v i))
      v)))

(defn vrange2 [n]
  (loop [i 0 v (transient [])]
    (if (< i n)
      (recur (inc i) (conj! v i))
      (persistent! v))))



(quick-bench (def v (vrange 1000000)))
"Elapsed time: 459.59 msecs"

(quick-bench (def v2 (vrange2 1000000)))
"Elapsed time: 379.85 msecs"
```

That's a slight speedup, but nothing like the 8x boost implied in the example docs?

Starting java in server mode changes the story, but still nothing like the docs..

```
(quick-bench (def v (vrange 1000000)))
"Elapsed time: 121.14 msecs"

(quick-bench (def v2 (vrange2 1000000)))
"Elapsed time: 75.15 msecs"
```

Is it that the persistent implementations have improved since the post about transients here: http://clojure.org/transients ?

What other factors might be contributing to the lack of boost with transients?

I'm using the OpenJDK java version 1.7 on ubuntu 12.04.  Maybe that's a lot slower than the (presumed) Hotspot 1.6 version used in the docs?  But wouldn't that imply BOTH tests should be slower by some constant, with the same gap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results are consistent with my experience with transients. I've used them quite a bit and I typically see a 2x performance improvement.

I tried this on Ubuntu 12.04, OpenJDK 1.7 with Clojure 1.6.0 and 1.7.0-alpha3. I get 2x performance with transients, slightly less than the 3x I get on OSX with the 1.8 Oracle jvm.

Also the above page is from the time of Clojure 1.2, and the performance of collections has improved significantly since then. I tried the experiment with 1.2 but Criterium doesn't work with it, so I had to use time just like on that page. Obviously the results are significantly variable (from 2x to 8x). I suspect the example in the documentation may have been cherry-picked.

Comment: Thanks Diego.  This was what I *hoped* was the reason.  In other words, it's not that transients are slower than reported in the docs, it's that the persistent collections are faster.